# Setup HttpClient proxy to access REST URL on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, httpclient

I have an EC2 image running and hosting a REST service accessible from a URL. The following is what I did:

1. `ssh -i <ec2-certificate> D port user@ec2-host`
2. Setup proxy in the firefox web browser and typed in the url `http://ec2-host:port/demo/workflow/lists/demo_workflow`

It works fine.

Now I need to send the GET method using a Java program; below is my code:

---

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("http://ec2-host:port/demo/workflow/lists/demo_workflow");
    HostConfiguration config = client.getHostConfiguration();
    config.setProxy(proxyHost, port);
    client.setHostConfiguration(config);

    try {
          client.executeMethod(method);
          if (method.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
             String response = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
             System.out.println("Response = " + response);
          }
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
          method.releaseConnection();
    }
```

---

But now I run into the exceptions below. Any tips?

> 010-08-11 16:46:34,781 INFO
>   [HttpMethodDirector] I/O exception
>   (org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException)
>   caught when processing request: The
>   server 184.72.46.209 failed to respond
>   2010-08-11 16:46:34,781 INFO 
>   [HttpMethodDirector] Retrying request
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException:
>   The server **[ec2-host]** failed to
>   respond   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1976)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
>     at ....[where my code throws
>   exception when invoking
>   client.executeMethod(config)]

Comment: You've used the `restlet` tag, how to this relate to the question?

Comment: Based on your commnet, I removed the restlet tag.